# Run IronPython script with .netStandard 2.1 without any manual dependencies

Tags: c#, ironpython, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.1

I have created one py script which imports my .netStandard classLibrary and runs its execution

The issue is, when my class library .netStandard version is 2.0 or less it runs properly,
But if the version is .netStandard 2.1 it asks for netStandard.dll as not found.

Now i have copied the .netStandard file from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.5' location and pasted with the Py script location and now it ran successfully.

I don't understand why specifically with .netStandard v2.1 the DLR with Iron python does not detect the netStandards dll. or are there are any steps i am missing?

Comment: Could you please provide more detail on how you are driving your ironpython execution?  Embedded in something? Through ipy.exe?

Comment: Yes @SimonOpelt,
I have downloaded ipy version 2.7.11 and using ipy.exe.
I am running on command line like this:  'ipy runnableScript.py'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing through the MSI package, `ipy.exe` is a dotnet 4.x application and therefore only compatible with dotnet standard up to version 2.0 as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support).

If you execute your python code hosted from within a dotnet core 3.x or dotnet 5 application (using the NuGet package) you will be able to execute it.

As discussed [here](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/issues/706) IronPython is not shipping an ipy.exe using dotnet core 3.x/dotnet 5 right now but using the ZIP-distributon you can `dotnet ipy.dll` (see `netcoreapp3.1` folder) or use the dotnet core 2.1 `ipy.bat` to launch your code.

Comment: I understand this, but was having one confusion. Check this git release link : 
'https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/releases/tag/ipy-2.7.10'. here they have wrote 'This release adds .NET Core 3.1 support.'

and check this link : 'https://ironpython.net/download/'. here they have mentioned 'IronPython also runs on .NET Core 2.0 and 2.1.'

So my doubt is can i call a dll with .net core 3.1 from ipy script?